# Tail the "in the last hour written lines from a log file" is it possible?

Tags: command-line, log

I am trying to grep looking for a pattern in to a log file, but I need the last hour of the log file. A tail -n XX will not work. Does anybody know if this is possible? Some kind of *tail the "in the last hour written lines from a log file"*

If there is any command or procedure I appreciate that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The tail it self will display the last lines but these can be all which were written in the last hour or only a part of them, if the log is being written swiftly. The grep comes later after a pipe |, to find a pattern in the last hour. Thx

Comment: tac command works backward of cat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say your log have the following structure:

```bsh
219.369.42.449 - - [05/Mar/2020:11:05:17 +0200] "log line"
219.369.42.449 - - [05/Mar/2020:11:06:37 +0200] "log line"
219.369.42.449 - - [05/Mar/2020:12:01:14 +0200] "log line"
219.369.42.449 - - [05/Mar/2020:12:07:23 +0200] "log line"
```

We can get all lines from the first occurrence of `05/Mar/2020:11` to the end `$` of the file by using `sed` in the following way:

```bsh
sed -n '/05\/Mar\/2020:11/,$p' "/path/to/file.log"
```

- The option `-n` will suppress the normal output of `sed`, but the flag `p` will print the matched part of the file.
- Note, if there isn't presented any record that mach to `05/Mar/2020:11`, `sed` wont provide any output.

We can automate the above by the help of the commands `date` and `eval`:

```bsh
COMMAND="sed -n '/$(LANG=C date --date='1 hour ago' "+%d\/%b\/%Y:%H")/,\$p'"
eval $COMMAND \"/path/to/file.log\"
```

- Using `sed` with double quote marks and variable within the expression doesn't provide the desired output in this case.
- So we first constructing the command as string and convert it to a real command by `eval`.
- `LANG=C` (`LANG=en_us_88591`) stands in order to get the desired date format, because, for example, in my case the default value of this envvar is `bg_BG.UTF-8`.

You can create a script, based on the two lines above - examples of such script:

- [apache2 : How to search a string from apache2 error logs in specific time range?](https://askubuntu.com/q/961722/566421)
- [`modsecurity-whitelist-rule-generator.bash`](https://github.com/pa4080/www-security-assistant/blob/master/modsecurity-whitelist-rule-generator.bash) - that parse *events* within ModSecutity's `modsec_audit.log` by *their unique-id*, and then generates whitelist rules for ModSecutity.

Answer (score 4):

There is no command or option to tail that will track changes in the past hour. You will have to grep the timestamps in the log or keep `tail -f` running and just scroll back when you need to check something. This has the advantage of also allowing you to catch events that happened 61 minutes ago.

Answer (score 3):

When you run your command every 5 minutes, also make a copy of the log file. Then you can diff from the 12th-last copy you made to get the current changes.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I normally take is:

```
tail -f {log}
```

This will have tail show messages -as they are written- to {log} and it will only end doing so when you stop the command. So what is shown is real time and logically also always within the current hour. The buffer size of the terminal session will be to where you can scroll back in time.

Comment: Thx for the response. The tail -f will work if the process is running all the time. The point is that I want to run a command every 5minutes that shows the last hour written lines in the log file, to grep the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the date command that @pa4080 used to get exactly one hour ago. Pass that to an awk script that finds the first line containing the correct year, month, day, and either the matching hour and higher minute or higher hour. Output from the first line to the end of file.

My awk isn't that strong or I'd write it for you. Hopefully someone else will be the awk master for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to everyone. 
I could handle the issue by using Zabbix, a monitoring tool.

@pa4080 that script would be the next opción. Thx

We can close this question.

Comment: The go to way of closing questions is by accepting an answer ...