# How can I extract text between lines containing timestamps?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm looking to text process an existing file and have the output of the alrorithm output to a new file.  I thought it would be an easy task, but it's flummoxing me, probably because I don't know ls from cat from awk at this point.

I have an existing very, very large text file that's formatted as:

```
00:02:00.100 --> 00:02:00.100
BLAH BLAH BLAH 

00:02:00.100 --> 00:02:00.100
BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

I basically am trying to output a txt file with just

```
BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

I can probably create a Word macro to do it as well, and even the all caps I could correct.

So far, I have

```
cat file.vtt | grep -v [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][[:space:]][[:punct:]][[:punct:]][[:punct:]][[:space:]][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

That outputs on the screen the results and it's definitely removed the timecode stamps, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to remove the hard returns between timecodes and just have the text lines flow.

The existing text file also uses >> to indicate a hard return.  Is there some way I could incorpoate that into the string, to insert a carriage return every time >> is in the existing file?

And finally, how in the world do I cause the original xyz.txt to be overrwritten with the output of the string?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example input, including an example with `>>` and multiple lines and the expected output for that? Use code formatting for the example output, input, and commands, please: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apache2 : How to search a string from apache2 error logs in specific time range?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961722/apache2-how-to-search-a-string-from-apache2-error-logs-in-specific-time-range)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `file.vtt` follows the Unix/Linux style `\n` and not Windows style `\r\n` carriage return(*If not, then run it through [dos2unix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183893) first.*) ... then,

```
awk '!/-->/ {sub(">>","\n"); printf("%s ", $0)}' file.vtt > xyz.txt
```

Will match and print lines(in `file.vtt`) not containing `-->` while removing any `\n` and substitute `>>` with `\n`(new line) then, redirect the output to `xyz.txt`(overwriting its contents if it exists or creating it if it doesn't).

**Alternatively**, to edit the original file `file.vtt`(**CAUTION ... replacing its contents**) instead, use `gawk` like so:

```
gawk -i inplace '!/-->/ {sub(">>","\n"); printf("%s ", $0)}' file.vtt
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I was actually incorrect.  It's not a .vtt file, but rather a Windows Notepad .txt file.

I received several awk syntax command line errors when trying the approach above.  It may seem like it would be simpler to just manually edit the file, but I have like 600 files, all over 6 hours of text, haha.

Comment: @ecceben Then run it through [dos2unix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1183893) first.

Comment: Thanks.  I ran it through dos2unix and it worked perfectly.  I used gawk instead of awk.